# Where can I download dwmapi.lib?

Tags: c, winapi, dwm, tdm-gcc

To use

> DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea

function we must have `dwmapi.lib` library.

I searched this library in my pc, but my pc doesn't find it.

So where can I download it?

Without it, my application doesn't compile properly; and shows me some errors:

```
undefined reference to DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea
collect2.exe error: ld returned 1 exit status.
```

I'm programming in c language using TDM_GCC compilers.

Please help me.

Comment: How is it that you have the header files to compile, but not the libs needed to link?

Comment: Locate libdwmapi.a first, then tell the linker to link it.  Note the file extension, it is not a .lib file in mingw land.

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the Windows SDK, which automatically gets installed with Visual Studio.

If you are you using a different set of compiler and tools, you can get the latest Windows SDK (all the headers and libs you need) from: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk